# Why does using the ".play" action not play this video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to make an image that, when clicked, will play a video, but when I click it the video doesn't play. I'm using a chromium browser.

```
<img src="overlay.png" onclick="playit();">
<video id="video" loop>
     <source src="wheel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
        

<script>
     function playit() {
            document.getElementById("video").play;
     }
</script>
```

I've put a `console.log()` message in the same script, and it executes succesfully, but nothing occurs with the `.play` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `play()` method like so:

```
function playit() {
    document.getElementById("video").play();
}
```

[More on `play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play)

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="overlay.png" onclick="playit();">
```

Remove semicolon ; when palyit function call with onclick event like this  onclick="playit()"